# Regex query in xml for retrieving value

Tags: c#

I have a XML file which has values inside like this:

```
<Root>
    <Request>
        <EmailInfo action="Test">
            <Subject>XYZ</Subject>
            <Body>Data</Body>
            <NextRunTime/>
            <ToMailBoxes>
                <ToMailBox>xyz@abc.com</ToMailBox>
            </ToMailBoxes>
            <FromMailBoxText>xyz@abc.com</FromMailBoxText>
            <UserID>XYZ</UserID>
            <Action>
                <Info>
                    <code></code>
                </Info>
            </Action>
            <ReplyTo />
        </EmailInfo>
    </Request>
</Root>
```

I need to get the value of `action` inside of the `EmailInfo` tag, which in this case is "Test".

I am using the above `for-each` loop, as there are many files, but I am not able to retrieve the value

How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use Regex. Use XmlDocument (or other xml reader). It is made specially for that.

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(xmlstring);

XmlNode errorNode = doc.DocumentElement.SelectSingleNode("/DataChunk/ResponseChunk/Errors/error");
```

EDIT: Sorry, the example XPath was not ment to work on you xml. It will be something like "/Request/EmailInfo/@action

Comment: tried the above method but not able to get the action value. It is coming as null.

Comment: @Divisadero, surely the XPath should be `/Root/Request/EmailInfo/@action`?

Comment: You are right, it was just an example for another xml...

Comment: Thanks that worked....